# Translate Chinese Seal (Characters identified: 天福紋銀)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I recently bought a small jade item and attempted to translate the seal on the bottom. After many hours of searching, I was unable to translate the characters. I believe they are Chinese characters, found some similar looking characters in small seal script but nothing matching what I have. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the character is a type called 经典繁方篆，a old standard chinese character around 1300BC to 1046BC

天福 is the name of a silver shop at TianJin during the period of the Republic of China(1912-1949)

纹银 means standard silver in ancient China

so the mean may be 天福's standard silver.

this probably a gift for their customers.